# Seeking References To MSVC 9.0's C++ Standards Compliance

Tags: c++, visual-c++, standards-compliance

I "know" (hopefully) that MSVC 9.0 Implements C++ 2003 ([ISO/IEC 14882:2003](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopenassist.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FC%252B%252B%2520Standard%2520-%2520ANSI%2520ISO%2520IEC%252014882%25202003.pdf&ei=50L9S5K8BIL8NbrItN4H&usg=AFQjCNG4-cbawIu_O0_KwFqjXU6VG1cZDA&sig2=Fw67fo2wEQ0zzESneqacCA)).  I am looking for a reference to this fact, and I am also looking for any research that has been done in to how compliant MSVC 9.0 is with that version of the Standard.

I have searched for and not been able to find a specific reference from MicroSoft that actually says something to the effect that MSVC implements C++ 2003.  Some of the out-of-date documentation says things like "[this release achieves roughly 98% compliance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289140(VS.71).aspx)" (when referring to MSVC .NET 2003's conformance to C++ 1997).  But I want a link to a document from MS that says "MSVC 9.0 implements blah," and another link to an independent group that has tested the conformance of MSVC 9.0.

Do you know of any such links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nonstandard Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x84h5b78%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) . Short summary

- Compiler Limits
- 10.3 (Paragraph 5) Covariant Return Types
- 14 export Keyword on a Template
- 14.6.2 Dependent Names
- 15.4 Function Exception Specifiers
- 16.3.2 The # Operator
- 21.1.1 Character Traits Requirements
- Storage Location of Objects

Comment: Based on the URL, these appear to apply to VS 8.0, not 9.0. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x84h5b78%28v=VS.90%29.aspx instead. I'm not sure there's any difference between the two, but this is is what's supposed to apply to 9.0...

Comment: @litb: Thanks, I did see this, but it doesn't specifically state what I'm looking for.  I can deduce from this that MSVC implements C++ 2003, but I don't want to deduce.  Moreover, in the section above this page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tb15w2z(v=VS.80).aspx) the only reference is to MSVC 7, not MSVC 9

Comment: BTW, I found you could tweak the URL to refer to MSVC 9.0.  Don't know if this is correct behavior for the site, but here's the tweaked link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x84h5b78(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: @John, ah thanks. Yes it seems they still admin that page. The VS8 page had some weird characters in it that the VS9 page removed. So i suspect the VS9 page is accurate. Incorporated the new URL.